# Multi-tenant Rails app and restricting access to controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for authentication, and I have "modules" in my rails app. I am trying to figure out the best approach to security. For example, here are the few things that I want to accomplish:

- I want the application controller to require login, unless they are accessing the `registrations` controller, in which case they are just submitting registration details.
- On the application level, I would like to define scopes, permitting access to certain controllers that the user's company has access to.
- Additionally, on each request, I want to verify that any IDs in the URL (whether it's a GET, POST, whatever), the user's company has access to that controller and ID in the parameter. (So they can't access Report ID 9 if their company doesn't have a report ID 9 associated with it)

I feel like this may be scalable, but I've never done this before so I'm not quite sure.

**Bullet 1**

In the ApplicationController, I would like to do something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user! unless controller == "Registrations"
end
```

I tried placing a `binding.pry` in the application controller, but the `controller_path` seems to always be `application`. Not sure if there's an easy way to accomplish this without going to each individual controller, which I'm hoping to avoid because I don't want to accidentally forget something when I add a new controller down the road (basically going against DRY).

Maybe I can implement a security controller and have every controller inherit from it? Never did this before but this might work if I can't accomplish what I'm trying to do in the Application Controller.

**Bullet 2**

I have tried to access Devise's `current_user` variable from the Application Controller, but it does not exist, so I'm not sure if I can check the user's permissions from the ApplicationController. Again, I'd love to avoid having to place this check in each controller because as the application expands, I may eventually forget to implement checks.

**EDIT**

So it looks like I have bullet 1 addressed, but now I'm trying to figure out the other 2. Being able to implement some type of "scope" or permission module at the application level. Any ideas?

Comment: Code like `before_action ... unless cond` is highly problematic. That `unless` condition is evaluated once and only once when the controller code itself is loaded, not each time the controller runs. You need [`skip_before_action`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) for that sort of thing.

Comment: Gotcha, so in this particular case, it sounds like I just need to manually implement `before_action :authenticate_user!` on every newly created controller? The `only` option seems to only work for actions, and I want to restrict all actions on all controllers unless it is the registrations controller.

Answer (score 1):

The `skip_before_action` directive can suppress execution of a `before_action` filter that's already defined. You can use this to turn off an action for a controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end

class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

The thing to note here is Ruby is a highly dynamic programming language and code can be executed *while the class is being defined*. It's important to pay close attention to when certain statements are run, as things like `unless`, the statement, tend to run *immediately* when in that context.

You'll see some others that allow deferred execution like in ActiveRecord with:

```
validates :name, unless: :anonymous?
```

Where that `validates` method has a specific option called `unless` which is distinct from the keyword `unless`. That defines a validation trigger with a condition attached to it.

On the other hand this code, while visually similar, is completely different:

```
validates :name unless anonymous?
```

This depends on a method called `anonymous?` being available at the class level and if it returns a non `nil` or `false` value will execute the `validates` function.

Comment: Gotcha. Great points and thanks for this information. This will allow me to accomplish the "require authenticated user unless they're accessing registration controller" portion of my objectives.

Comment: It's a fairly common pattern to require registration except, of course, when you're trying to register someone in the first place. As a note you may want to make a `RegistrationRequiredController` base class that requires registration with that `before_action` and inherit from that instead for all controllers that require registration. You may need to have other controllers that are available to non-registered users, so it's worth considering that approach. The downside is you'll need to be vigilant to inherit properly or your controllers won't be properly restricted.

Comment: Gotcha. Makes sense. I've noted that down too for just in case I do need another controller to be available. I really appreciate it!